# TypeError: Cannot read property 'projectPath' of undefined when create amplify

Tags: angular, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I try to build a web app , using front-end as angular and back-end as amplify.

I created angular app after that i add the following src/polyfills.ts file to recreate them:

```
(window as any).process = {
  env: { DEBUG: undefined },
};
```

Next step i create new amplify back-end

```
amplify init
```

after showing this error:

```
Note: It is recommended to run this command from the root of your app directory
? Enter a name for the project amplifyapp
The following configuration will be applied:

Project information
| Name: amplifyapp
| Environment: dev
| Default editor: Visual Studio Code
| App type: javascript
TypeError: Cannot read property 'projectPath' of undefined
    at getAngularConfig (/snapshot/node_modules/amplify-frontend-javascript/lib/framework-config-mapping.js:57:52)
    at getProjectConfiguration (/snapshot/node_modules/amplify-frontend-javascript/lib/framework-config-mapping.js:85:14)
    at Object.displayFrontendDefaults (/snapshot/node_modules/amplify-frontend-javascript/lib/configuration-manager.js:173:32)
    at Object.displayFrontendDefaults (/snapshot/node_modules/amplify-frontend-javascript/index.js:40:24)
    at displayAndSetDefaults (/snapshot/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/init-steps/s0-analyzeProject.js:83:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async analyzeProject (/snapshot/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/init-steps/s0-analyzeProject.js:99:9)
    at async Object.run (/snapshot/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/commands/init.js:29:13)
    at async Object.executeAmplifyCommand (/snapshot/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/index.js:236:9)
    at async executePluginModuleCommand (/snapshot/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/execution-manager.js:164:5)
    at async Object.executeCommand (/snapshot/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/execution-manager.js:35:9)
    at async Object.run (/snapshot/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/index.js:112:9)
```

Comment: I'm getting this, too. Actively trying to solve it. I'm new to `amplify`, but not angular, node, etc. Let's collaborate. GitHub messaging might be best for an extended conversation and we can come back here and document a solution. If you find one, please answer your question and ping me. If I find one, I promise to do the same.

Comment: Looks like a known issue. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/7057 or https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/7060#issuecomment-817464402 list potential fixes until they release an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using version 4.47.1 of the `amplify` cli and also experiencing this issue. From @Tyr52 comment on the question above, I was able to go to the GitHub known issue [link](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/7057) and find a command to run that appears to workaround the problem. As I am new to `amplify` I'm not sure it completely fixes any problem that was created, but it appears to allow me to continue with the [AWS tutorial](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/angular#create-a-new-angular-app) I was following.

Commands:

```
amplify env add
# init command may not be needed, but I did it anyway
amplify init
```